# For loop in nested Query

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have 2 tables as defined in the below image.

[image: Table Structure and Data]

Now I want to query the "match table" with following checks;

1. UserA in FromUser
2. FromUser Rating is less than 0 or undefined.

Result should be:

1. Match Table Object
2. Must have count of meetings like UserA have 3 meetings with userB and 3 meetings with userC. so the result should be like following:

[{id:"",fromUser:"",toUser:"",MeetingCount:3},{id:"",fromUser:"",toUser:"",MeetingCount:3}]

How can I achieve this? What I tried so far:

I queried the match table and now I want to loop against each `matchId` from match detail table to get its data.

```
matQueryFrom.equalTo("FROM_USER_OBJECTID",user.id);
matQueryFrom.find().then(function(matchObjects){
    if(matchObjects!=undefined && matchObjects.length>0){
        var returnList = [];
        for(var i=0;i<matchObjects.length;i++){
            var vrmatchObj = matchObjects[i];
            var matDetailQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("VR_MATCH_DETAIL"));
            matDetailQuery.equalTo("VRMatches", vrmatchObj.id);
            matDetailQuery.find().then(function(detailArray){
                returnList.push(detailArray);
            }).then(function(){console.log(returnList);});
        }
        return returnList;
    }
});
```

Can anyone guide me how can i achieve this? Currently the returnList is always empty.

Comment: Where we come to know from the Match Detail table which user has meeting with which user?

Comment: TableA pointer is the match table pointer. It will tell that these 2 user will meet